# Coreinfo - difference between the PREFETCHW and 3DNOW

Tags: windows, cpu, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5, x86

After reading the about 3DNOW instruction set extension, I found that prefetchw is one of 3DNOW's instructions.

I wanted to know if my CPU supports the instruction PREFETCHW, I ran coreinfo and got these lines:

```
3DNOW           -       Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT        -       Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
PREFETCHW       *       Supports PREFETCHW instruction
```

what's the difference between the PREFETCHW and 3DNOW?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered in the [Wikipedia article on 3DNow!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DNow!), in the second paragraph:

> AMD announced on August 2010 that support for 3DNow would be dropped in future AMD processors, except for two instructions (the `PREFETCH` and `PREFETCHW` instructions). The two instructions are also available in Bay-Trail Intel processors.

Comment: So coreinfo's PREFETCHW is what indicates if my cpu supports prefetchw instruction or not? And not 3DNOW?

Comment: @super-user 3DNow support implies that PREFETCHW is available. Availability of PREFETCHW doesn't necessarily mean entire 3DNow set is available.